# arcpy.GetParameterAsText not passing arguments to script?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, parameters, python-toolbox, oserror

I have been working on an ArcGIS Python script tool which takes the co-ordinate system from an input raster and reprojects a vector to the same co-ordinate system.

The script works fine when i hard code the addresses for the workspace and input datasets. But as soon as I try to pass those as parameters in a toolbox it no longer works.

Can anyone here point out what I am doing wrong?

```py
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]

class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Test_tool"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input workspace",
            name="workspace",
            datatype="DEWorkspace",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input classified raster",
            name="input_raster",
            datatype="GPRasterLayer",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input features",
            name="input_features",
            datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        params = [param0, param1, param2]

        return params

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""

        # Define some paths/variables
        outWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
        arcpy.env.workspace = outWorkspace
        input_raster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
        input_features = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

        output_features = outWorkspace + "\\projected.shp"

        out_coordinate_system = arcpy.Describe(input_raster).spatialReference
        proj_grid = arcpy.Project_management(input_features, output_features, out_coordinate_system)

        return
```

When I run the tool it provides the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 75, in execute
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1245, in Describe
    return gp.describe(value, data_type)
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 370, in describe
    self._gp.Describe(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
OSError: "" does not exist
 Failed to execute (Tool).
```

it seems to me that the input variables of the parameters are not being passed correctly.

Comment: Try arcpy.GetParameter() instead of arcpy.GetParameterAsText()

Comment: arcpy.GetParameter() did not work. What did work was: parameters[].valueAsText  Thanks for the assistance tho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code that you have presented is for a Python Toolbox (`*.pyt`) for which you need to use the `Parameter` class.

`GetParameter()` and `GetParameterAsText()` are only used with Python Script tools in Standard Toolboxes (`*.tbx`).

Answer (score 5):

Using the [answer from @PolyGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/324239/115) my corrected code is as follows:

```
import arcpy


class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]


class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Test_tool"
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input workspace",
            name="workspace",
            datatype="DEWorkspace",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input classified raster",
            name="input_raster",
            datatype="GPRasterLayer",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Input features",
            name="input_features",
            datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")


        params = [param0, param1, param2]

        return params

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""

        # Define some paths/variables
        outWorkspace = parameters[0].valueAsText
        arcpy.env.workspace = outWorkspace
        output_location = parameters[0].valueAsText
        input_raster = parameters[1].valueAsText
        input_features = parameters[2].valueAsText

        output_features = output_location + "\\projected.shp"

        out_coordinate_system = arcpy.Describe(input_raster).spatialReference
        proj_grid = arcpy.Project_management(input_features, output_features, out_coordinate_system)

        return
```